# CSS breathing <button> stop text from shaking

Tags: html, css

I have a round breathing `click me` button beneath, here I am using `@keyframes` to animate the button breathing - so far all good!

But as you can tell the `click me` text is shaking during the breathing animation.

Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}

button.circle {
  --startSize: 65vh;
  --endSize: 85vh;
  width: var(--startSize);
  height: var(--startSize);
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-name: breathe;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
    border: none;

}

@keyframes breathe {
  
  0% {
    width: var(--startSize); 
    height: var(--startSize);
  }
  
  25% {
    width: var(--startSize); 
    height: var(--startSize);
  }

  75% {
    width: var(--endSize);
    height: var(--endSize);
  }
  
  100% {
    width: var(--endSize);
    height: var(--endSize);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><button class="circle centered">Click me</button></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a better way to animate this would be to use `transform: scale(...)` on the `::after` pseudo-element. Using this method we get the following benefits:

1. The animation no longer affects document flow<sup>1</sup>. When animating, [prefer `transform` and `opacity` over properties like `width` or `height`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animations-and-performance). The latter will affect the elements around it (the document flow). Transforms are purely visual - they have no affect on other elements in terms of placement, which means [improved performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/).
2. The text is separate from the animation which means no more shakiness.

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}

button.circle {
  width: 65vh;
  height: 65vh;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

button.circle::after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: breathe 4.5s ease infinite alternate running;
}

@keyframes breathe {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to { transform: scale(1.4); }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><button class="circle centered">Click me</button></a>
```

Note: [Browser support for this method](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

---

<sup>1. I realize the button is centered and positioned `absolute` which means it isn't affecting document flow to begin with. That said, this method of animating with transforms is more flexible for either scenario.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the transform property you're using to centre the button. I've put a JSFiddle together using the grid property to centre the button horizontally and vertically, which stops the text shaking.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.circle-outer {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button.circle {
  --startSize: 65vh;
  --endSize: 85vh;
  width: var(--startSize);
  height: var(--startSize);
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-name: breathe;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  border: none;
}

@keyframes breathe {
  0% {
    width: var(--startSize);
    height: var(--startSize);
  }
  25% {
    width: var(--startSize);
    height: var(--startSize);
  }
  75% {
    width: var(--endSize);
    height: var(--endSize);
  }
  100% {
    width: var(--endSize);
    height: var(--endSize);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-outer">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><button class="circle">Click me</button></a>
</div>
```

And a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/WebDevelopWolf/7ujm2L5v/11/

Comment: Your example shakes in exactly the same way as OPs in both the StackSnippet and JSFiddle. In fact, I think it may even be slightly worse. Chrome 71.0.3578.98